# Include external javascript in JSF page through bean varaible?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

Generally we used `<h:outputScript />` to refer local scripts and for refering external Java Script we used `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>`.

Now my issue is how to refer those java script which dynamically loading through some other url for my case i have to refer this javascript `http://150.190.135.41:8700/iportal/jsapi` for the time being i am using like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://150.190.135.41:8700/iportal/jsapi" />
```

but for me its not a right approach it should be dynamic ,so i added this `http://150.190.135.41:8700/iportal/jsapi` to a properties file and now in jsf bean i initialize a variable with this url.

Now can any one tell me how to access it into XHTML of JSF Page? This dynamic access needed because ip of **iportal** would be different for different client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have address in your backing bean then you can do simply

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="#{bean.dynamicAddres}" />
```